# twisted module of python3 portion missing on osx

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, twisted, twisted.application

I can only find portion of twisted in my python3 on OSX but complete in python2,

Some important packages missing here, such as

```
twisted.application
```

It will be the same result no matter  whether by download complete package or by run pip3

```
python3 setup3.py install
```

or

```
sudo pip3 install twisted

$ tree -L 2 /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/twisted 
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/twisted
├── __init__.py
├── __pycache__
│   ├── __init__.cpython-34.pyc
│   ├── _version.cpython-34.pyc
│   └── copyright.cpython-34.pyc
├── _version.py
├── copyright.py
├── cred
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── _digest.py
│   ├── credentials.py
│   ├── error.py
│   └── test
├── internet
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── _baseprocess.py
│   ├── _glibbase.py
│   ├── _newtls.py
│   ├── _posixstdio.py
│   ├── _signals.py
│   ├── _sslverify.py
│   ├── abstract.py
│   ├── address.py
│   ├── base.py
│   ├── default.py
│   ├── defer.py
│   ├── endpoints.py
│   ├── epollreactor.py
│   ├── error.py
│   ├── fdesc.py
│   ├── gireactor.py
│   ├── gtk3reactor.py
│   ├── interfaces.py
│   ├── kqreactor.py
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── pollreactor.py
│   ├── posixbase.py
│   ├── process.py
│   ├── protocol.py
│   ├── reactor.py
│   ├── selectreactor.py
│   ├── ssl.py
│   ├── task.py
│   ├── tcp.py
│   ├── test
│   ├── threads.py
│   ├── udp.py
│   └── utils.py
├── logger
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── _buffer.py
│   ├── _file.py
│   ├── _filter.py
│   ├── _flatten.py
│   ├── _format.py
│   ├── _global.py
│   ├── _io.py
│   ├── _json.py
│   ├── _legacy.py
│   ├── _levels.py
│   ├── _logger.py
│   ├── _observer.py
│   ├── _stdlib.py
│   ├── _util.py
│   └── test
├── names
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── _rfc1982.py
│   ├── _version.py
│   ├── cache.py
│   ├── client.py
│   ├── common.py
│   ├── dns.py
│   ├── error.py
│   ├── hosts.py
│   ├── resolve.py
│   ├── root.py
│   └── test
├── protocols
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── basic.py
│   ├── loopback.py
│   ├── policies.py
│   ├── test
│   └── tls.py
├── python
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── _tzhelper.py
│   ├── compat.py
│   ├── components.py
│   ├── constants.py
│   ├── context.py
│   ├── deprecate.py
│   ├── dist.py
│   ├── dist3.py
│   ├── failure.py
│   ├── filepath.py
│   ├── lockfile.py
│   ├── log.py
│   ├── modules.py
│   ├── monkey.py
│   ├── procutils.py
│   ├── randbytes.py
│   ├── reflect.py
│   ├── runtime.py
│   ├── systemd.py
│   ├── test
│   ├── threadable.py
│   ├── threadpool.py
│   ├── urlpath.py
│   ├── usage.py
│   ├── util.py
│   ├── versions.py
│   └── win32.py
├── test
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── iosim.py
│   ├── proto_helpers.py
│   ├── reflect_helper_IE.py
│   ├── reflect_helper_VE.py
│   ├── reflect_helper_ZDE.py
│   ├── ssl_helpers.py
│   ├── test_abstract.py
│   ├── test_compat.py
│   ├── test_context.py
│   ├── test_cooperator.py
│   ├── test_defer.py
│   ├── test_defgen.py
│   ├── test_error.py
│   ├── test_factories.py
│   ├── test_failure.py
│   ├── test_fdesc.py
│   ├── test_internet.py
│   ├── test_iosim.py
│   ├── test_iutils.py
│   ├── test_lockfile.py
│   ├── test_log.py
│   ├── test_loopback.py
│   ├── test_modules.py
│   ├── test_monkey.py
│   ├── test_paths.py
│   ├── test_policies.py
│   ├── test_process.py
│   ├── test_randbytes.py
│   ├── test_reflect.py
│   ├── test_setup.py
│   ├── test_ssl.py
│   ├── test_sslverify.py
│   ├── test_task.py
│   ├── test_tcp.py
│   ├── test_tcp_internals.py
│   ├── test_threadable.py
│   ├── test_threadpool.py
│   ├── test_threads.py
│   ├── test_twisted.py
│   ├── test_udp.py
│   ├── test_usage.py
│   └── testutils.py
├── trial
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── _asyncrunner.py
│   ├── _asynctest.py
│   ├── _synctest.py
│   ├── itrial.py
│   ├── reporter.py
│   ├── test
│   ├── unittest.py
│   └── util.py
└── web
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __pycache__
    ├── _newclient.py
    ├── _responses.py
    ├── _version.py
    ├── client.py
    ├── error.py
    ├── html.py
    ├── http.py
    ├── http_headers.py
    ├── iweb.py
    ├── resource.py
    ├── script.py
    ├── server.py
    ├── static.py
    ├── test
    └── util.py

27 directories, 167 files

# longqi at LQMacPro.local in ~/Downloads/Twisted-15.2.1 [18:56:34]
$
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry. All of this is because the twisted team is still working on the porting process.

https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/Plan/Python3